# Getting values from enum class where enum member names are known at run time in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I am trying to get enum values from Enum class by getting enum member name runtime . I am trying in the following way:

```
from enum import Enum


    class EnumList(Enum):

        foo = 1
        bar = 2
```

```
enumMemberName=input("Enter enum member name")
enumValue=repr(EnumList.enumMemberName)          // **AttributeError: enumMemberName**
enumValue=repr(EnumList.foo)                     // **working fine**
```

please provide me with the alternate solution of above problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

**edit**: revised answer after OP feedback.

```
from enum import Enum


class EnumList(Enum):

    foo = 1
    bar = 2


enumMemberName=input("Enter enum member name")

enumMember = EnumList.foo
enumMemberTwo = EnumList[enumMemberName]

enumValue = EnumList[enumMemberName].value
enumValueStr = repr(EnumList[enumMemberName].value)
```

Quoting from the [documentation for Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)

[image: From Enum documentation]

Comment: the above solution gives output in the following format:<EnumList.foo: 1>                            but the expected output is : 1

Comment: @triptisinha  answer was revised.

Answer (score 2):

Your expectations are wrong.  Asking an `Enum` for one of its members is going to give you that member:

```
>>> enumList[enumMemberName]   # if name is 'foo'  (also, notice square brackets)
<EnumList.foo: 1>              # expected output
```

If you specifically want the value, you have to ask for it:

```
>>> enumList[enumMemberName].value   # if name is 'foo'
1
```